# Unsourcing bash in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I typed command

```
source $HOME/$USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

And there was no such file actually.

Now whenever I open command prompt I get that message

> /home/cse/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

How to get rid of this?

Comment: show us your ~/.BASH_PROFILE and your ~/.BASHRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already added the file at .bash_profile or .bashrc ? If yes and the file does not exist then this is why you see this message. You must remove it from these files then you will not see this message.

Comment: Thank you.. I changed it in .bashrc file and it solved .